# jquery append and html does not run but remove does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code below, I am trying to add a `<tr>` on button click:

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
$("#gtab").append("<tr><td width='34%'><textarea style='width:290px; height:100px'> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. </textarea></td>  <td width='33%'><textarea style='width:290px; height:100px'> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. </textarea></td> <td width='33%'><input type='button' value='Del' onclick='$(this).parent().parent().remove();'></td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" align="center" id="gt1" class="gtab"></table>
<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='nr();'>
```

Comment: your id is different or use class selector as `$(".gtab")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've two problem here

1. You did not create event listener to handle button click action.
2. You've selecting object using class but you call using `#` instead `.`

Check my snippet below.

```js
function nr() {
  $(".gtab").append("<tr><td width='34%'><textarea style='width:290px; height:100px'> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. </textarea></td>  <td width='33%'><textarea style='width:290px; height:100px'> At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. </textarea></td> <td width='33%'><input type='button' value='Del' onclick='$(this).parent().parent().remove();'></td></tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="100%" align="center" id="gt1" class="gtab"></table>

<input type='button' value='Add' onclick='nr();'>
```

Comment: @user6526215: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your id is `gt1` so change

```
$("#gtab")
```

to

```
$("#gt1")
```

where is the implementation of `nr()`? I hope that line is inside it.